# How De-serialize response JSON with dynamic keys?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, json.net, unity-ui

I know that this question is asked many times but still I'm struggling to understand this. I have below json to c# converted class.

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class Accessibility
{
    public bool share { get; set; }
    public bool comment { get; set; }
}

public class Avatar
{
    public string @base { get; set; }
}

public class Beautifulnari
{
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
    public long totalViewsCount { get; set; }
}

public class CaptionSignals
{
    public bool safe { get; set; }
    public Unsafe @unsafe { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Count
{
    public int likes { get; set; }
    public int views { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public Haythandi haythandi { get; set; }
    public Beautifulnari beautifulnari { get; set; }
}

public class HashtagDatum
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string hashTagId { get; set; }
    public string hashtagName { get; set; }
}

public class Haythandi
{
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
    public int totalViewsCount { get; set; }
}

public class Loc
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class MediaLocation
{
    public int isHLS { get; set; }
    public bool isTranscoded { get; set; }
    public double duration { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public string thumbNailPath { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public int mediaType { get; set; }
    public string f0 { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public Transcoded transcoded { get; set; }
    public string compressedThumbnailPath { get; set; }
    public string oPath { get; set; }
    public string resizedThumbnailPath { get; set; }
    public Resolution resolution { get; set; }
    public Thumbnails thumbnails { get; set; }
    public string webPath { get; set; }
}

public class ModerationStatus
{
    public int approval { get; set; }
    public int payment { get; set; }
    public bool isModerated { get; set; }
    public string moderatedBy { get; set; }
    public string approvedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? approvalDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? moderationDate { get; set; }
    public int isAccepted { get; set; }
    public string acceptedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime acceptanceDate { get; set; }
    public object hashtagRejectReason { get; set; }
    public int isOriginalAudio { get; set; }
    public object ogAudioAcceptedBy { get; set; }
    public object ogAudioAcceptanceDate { get; set; }
    public object ogAudioRejectReason { get; set; }
    public string acceptedHashtagId { get; set; }
}

public class ModerationV2Array
{
    public string moderatorId { get; set; }
    public string moderatorName { get; set; }
    public object moderationSignals { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
}

public class OwnerData
{
    public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string profilePic { get; set; }
    public int isProfileVerified { get; set; }
    public int isFollowed { get; set; }
    public int tipEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public MediaLocation mediaLocation { get; set; }
    public TempMedia tempMedia { get; set; }
    public Song song { get; set; }
    public Count count { get; set; }
    public Accessibility accessibility { get; set; }
    public OwnerData ownerData { get; set; }
    public ModerationStatus moderationStatus { get; set; }
    public TaggedStatus taggedStatus { get; set; }
    public List<string> etags { get; set; }
    public bool isDuplicate { get; set; }
    public bool isProcessed { get; set; }
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public List<string> hashtagIds { get; set; }
    public string youtubeLink { get; set; }
    public bool isPrivate { get; set; }
    public int reportPostsCount { get; set; }
    public string audioLang { get; set; }
    public object cta_text { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string versionCode { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string postType { get; set; }
    public string uploadSource { get; set; }
    public bool isSpam { get; set; }
    public bool isPremium { get; set; }
    public int metaProcessed { get; set; }
    public int isShoppable { get; set; }
    public int isLiked { get; set; }
    public bool onlyFollowers { get; set; }
    public bool isPrivateByAdmin { get; set; }
    public int isPinned { get; set; }
    public int isPromoted { get; set; }
    public int isMiningAllowed { get; set; }
    public string s3RefId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public object duplicateOfPostId { get; set; }
    public List<HashtagDatum> hashtagData { get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public int shareCount { get; set; }
    public int likeCount { get; set; }
    public int commentCount { get; set; }
    public int viewsCount { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public List<object> spamReason { get; set; }
    public List<object> taggedUsers { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public Loc loc { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public bool? enableV2 { get; set; }
    public List<ModerationV2Array> moderationV2Array { get; set; }
    public bool? ignoreV2 { get; set; }
    public bool? isPremiumV2 { get; set; }
    public bool? isSpamV2 { get; set; }
    public List<PremiumCCSignal> premiumCCSignals { get; set; }
}

public class PremiumCCSignal
{
    public string moderatorId { get; set; }
    public CaptionSignals captionSignals { get; set; }
}

public class Resolution
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public bool hasmoreData { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string art { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public object albumName { get; set; }
    public int startTime { get; set; }
    public double endTime { get; set; }
    public string acrId { get; set; }
}

public class TaggedStatus
{
    public bool isTagged { get; set; }
    public string taggedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime taggedDate { get; set; }
}

public class TempMedia
{
    public int isHls { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnails
{
    public string w50 { get; set; }
    public string w150 { get; set; }
    public string w300 { get; set; }
    public string w700 { get; set; }
}

public class Transcoded
{
    public string p1024 { get; set; }
    public string p480 { get; set; }
    public string p720 { get; set; }
}

public class Unsafe
{
}
```

In this above JSON, classes mentioned below are dynamic keys into response JSON.

```
 Haythandi

Beautifulnari
```

The problem is that values Haythandi and beautifulNari as class name (if convert to c#) which are actually ids of that particular record. How do I convert  these id's into c# class?, I have tried multiple approaches like using Dictionaries, JObjects, dynamic and Expando classes but not result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the json?

Comment: Hey @tymtam, thank you for reply actually I tried adding JSON but its response is too long. Is it okay if I share some Image snippets?

Comment: Hey @tymtam I have added initial lines of json as Image in question above please do check and let me know, Thanks

Comment: @OmkarP You are violating the rules of this resource. Psl replace the image by text. We need the real json string to test the solution

Comment: @Serge I have added the JSON in place of c# class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need change one of the 'character classes' to:

```
public class MyClassWithPosts // was Beautifulnari
{
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
    public long totalViewsCount { get; set; }
}
```

After that `data` can become a dictionary (update: a list of dictionaries):

```
public class Root
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, MyClassWithPosts>> data { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hey @tymtam Thank s for reply I tried the above method , but I'm Getting below error Get failed: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,ClassWithPosts]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: I'd need to see the json, a least the part with `Beautifulnari` to figure it out then.

Comment: @tymtamI have changed the question and added initial lines of json response as an Image please check and let me know, and thank you for help.

Comment: Try with a `List` of dictionaries...

Comment: I have added the JSON please check